# Winsock - Best way to read, write, send, and receive from sockets

Tags: c++, sockets, networking, winsock, winsock2

What is the best way to read and write from multiple client sockets on a single thread? I've heard that `select()` is oldschool and there are better options available. Is the best option currently to use one of `WSAAsyncSelect`, `WSAEventSelect`?

Also, what is the difference between `WSARecv()` and `recv()`, and `WSASend()` and `send()`? Are the WSA versions the most modern way to send and recv data through winsock?

Comment: The best option is generally to **drop** the requirement for a single thread and use an event-based model. All of the newer network libraries (e.g. boost) support that. If you don't want such a lib, use IOCP.

Comment: send()/WSASend() and recv()/WSARecv() are aliases. They were defined decades ago. Nothing 'most modern' about any of them.

Comment: @EJP: They are NOT aliases for anything.  They are their own distinct functions.  `WSASend()` and `WSARecv()` are extensions provided by WinSock2 (so not portable to other platforms), and they support I/O Completion Ports, which is the best way to write scalable socket code on Windows, so they are "modern".

Comment: Thanks Remy, i'll look at completion ports.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your single thread is also implementing a GUI then WSAAsyncSelect is designed for this purpose: You get your socket notifications through messages in the Windows queue that your GUI thread must service anyway.

If your single thread is dedicated to the sockets and does not need a message loop, then WSAEventSelect might be more convenient, and a little faster.

Comment: Oh ok. I'm using Opengl as my GUI, so i'll go with the former. Thanks!